# How to reset simulators for specific Xcode version using fastlane?

Tags: xcode, fastlane

Within `gitlab-ci.yml` I have:

```
test:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - killall "Simulator" || true
  script:
    //how can I select proper xcode here?
    - bundle exec fastlane snapshot reset_simulators --force
    - bundle exec fastlane test
  after_script:
    - killall "Simulator" || true
    - rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives || true
  artifacts:
    name: "Staff_${CI_PIPELINE_ID}"
    paths:
      - fastlane/output/coverage
  when: on_success
  tags:
    - iOS
```

**Why do I need to do that?**

Because `reset_simulators --force` resets simulators for different xcode version than I use;) How can I force it to select good xcode version?

Answer (score 1):

If you want this for `scan` or `run_tests`

It now supports
`reset_simulator`

> Enabling this option will automatically erase the simulator before running the application
>
> SCAN_RESET_SIMULATOR

just call

```
xcversion(version: 11.0)
run_tests(
    reset_simulator: true
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have your own `Fastfile` which has your `test` lane. I would suggest that you reset the simulators in there. Then add the [`xcode_select`](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/xcode_select/) call before the reset.

For example:

```
lane :test do
  xcode_select('/Applications/Xcode9.4.1.app')
  Snapshot::ResetSimulators.clear_everything!(nil, true) # what reset_simulators ends up calling
  # your other code
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the fastlane action "reset_simulator_contents"

This will reset all simulators running on the test machine.